# Minipage overflowing the page, margins and paddings calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, minipage

I want a page divided in 4 ideal columns, each column with a picture and some text; the text should be aligned on the left, the tikz figure on top should be centered.

That's what I did so far

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    a4paper,
    margin=0pt
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\NewDocumentCommand\mFigure{mm}{
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
        \centering
        \noindent
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            {#1}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \newline
        \begin{flushleft}
            {#2}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mFigureTriangle}{o}{
    \mFigure{
        \coordinate[label={left:$A$}]  (A) at (0.0,0.0);
        \coordinate[label={right:$B$}] (B) at (1.0,0.0);
        \coordinate[label={above:$C$}] (C) at (0.5,1.0);
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    }
    {
        \lipsum[8]
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \mFigureTriangle
    \mFigureTriangle
    \mFigureTriangle
    \mFigureTriangle
\end{document}
```

This code has several problems:

- the 4th minipage overflows the page and in general each minipage doesn't really look like is really `0.25\linewidth` wide
- the tikz figure itself doesn't look like it's really centered relative to the minipage itself

I would also like to:

- create precise divisions for the minipage, 1/4th of the width
- have some internal padding inside the minipage

What should I look for ?

Comment: Remove the blank lines between the minipages.  Better yet, use paracol.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I didn't know that, `paracol`is probably the best answer yet

Comment: If you use paracol, you will need `\globalcounter*` for the captions.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I learned a new interesting package for me. I erased my answer which was much less good.